# JSON parsing in Javascript with no known number of items

Tags: javascript, json

I'm drawing a blank with the best way to process JSON data which will be of the following form:

```
[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"}, 
 {"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]

var p = '[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"}, 
          {"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]',
```

It will also be of variable length.
I'm having trouble looking through all the data pairs pulling off the latlng values.
I'm using the code:

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
```

}

from this other SO question: [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-json-object)

However, the formats in the above example are different from mine.
How do I loop through each key/value in turn until the JSON string is exhausted?
I'm a little new to JSON and Javascript.

Comment: So each object can have more properties than just `latlng`? Or what is the problem? `p` in your example is a string, are you parsing the JSON properly in your actual code?

Comment: Note that I corrected the question you linked to. The OP had a JavaScript object, not JSON. The same goes for you. After you parsed the JSON, you have a JavaScript array. I assume you know how to iterate over arrays, if not, have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: I voted to close this question. It is not clear what your problem is. If you don't know how to iterate over arrays, read the MDN JavaScript Guide, as I already said (you have to learn the basics). If you don't know how to parse JSON, have a look at [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object). How to iterate over properties of an object is explained in the question you linked to. You just have to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `JSON.parse` (on any remotely modern browser) to take a json string and get the relevant javascript structure. Once you have that, you can iterate over the structure.

So you start with

`var json = '[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"}, {"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]';`

and then you can get a javascript array by

`var ary = JSON.parse(json);`

From here you are just a hop skip and jump away from iterating over your array, getting the current element, and doing what you want.

Note for your structure, instead of returning

`{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"}`

for each element in the array, you should do

`{"lat":"42.6674996","long": "-71.1786423"}`

that way as you iterate over the array, you can do something like

...in your for loop

```
var current = ary[i];
var lat = current.lat;
var long = current.long;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery.parseJSON - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var json = '[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"},{"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]';
var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);

$.each(parsed, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value['latlng']);
});
```

or the native [JSON.parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js):

```
var json = '[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"},{"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var count = parsed.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    console.log(parsed[i]['latlng']);
```

Comment: What if he does not use jQuery?

Comment: Why should he reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Using `JSON.parse` and a simple `for` loop is not reinventing the wheel IMO. I would not include a whole library to do something which the language provides natively.

Comment: What if that wheel doesn't fit his car? Suggesting jQuery on questions that aren't tagged as jQuery should be left as comments, IMO. At least, add a disclaimer. In this case, OP can just use JSON.parse from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js which fits most needs since it's a lot lighter than jQuery

Comment: There, I added the use of native json.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to turn that string into an object before you can iterate through it safely:

```
var p = JSON.parse('[{"latlng":"42.6674996,-71.1786423"}, {"latlng":"53.8136722,-1.7301123"}]');

for(key = 0; key < p.length; key++) { // Start the key at zero, increment until it his the object's length
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // If the item has a key
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);  // Alert the key and then the item. 
  }
}
```

In your case, you have a multidimensional object. So each return will give you another object. How I would deal with this is by traversing the returned object like so:

```
alert(p[key]['latlng']);
```

To have a better understanding of this, look at the initial object syntax...

```
[
  { // key 0
    "latlng": "42.68, -71.18" // key 'latlng'
  },
  { // key 1
    "latlng": "53.81, -1.73" // key 'latlng'
  }
]
```

So essentially you're traversing the object using the values that the loop increments. If you have an object with 5 items your loop will grab that number and cycle through 5 times (0 .. 4). Each time it loops the incremented `key` variable will be used to select your item, and from there you can grab the the `latlng` key and return its value within the nested object.

Comment: You should not iterate over an array with `for...in`.